# JQuery not detecting id element in partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an id element "Remove" (in a partial view) clicking on which shall remove the producerId from a movie. When I click on it, the jquery function is not responding and nothing happens. Please help me to see what is going wrong here.

Here is my view html (_ProducerIndex.cshtml) -

```
@model MovieInfo.Models.Producer

@if (Model != null)
{
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="removeproducer" data-mi-producerId="@Model.ProducerId" data-mi-movieid="@ViewData["Movie"]">
                <a href="#">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

}

And here is what my jquery is doing -

```
$(function () {

var removeProducer = function () {

    var $a = $(this);
    var prodId = $a.attr("data-mi-producerid");
    var mov = $a.attr("data-mi-movieId");

    var options = {
        url: "/Movie/ProducerRemove",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ producerId: prodId, movie: mov }),
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html"
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $("#producerindex");
        $target.html(data);
    });

    return false;
};

$("#removeproducer").on("click", removeProducer);
});
```

I tried putting alert statement in removeProducer function but it is not getting called.

Comment: Is your on'click' setup happening at a time after the document has finished loading?  Make sure it is inside $(document).ready().

Comment: It is in $(document).ready() just like my other jquery functions.

Comment: Can you see any errors in console?

Comment: Where exactly can I check that? (as it so happens I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and JQuery). Also want to add that this html is generated from a partial view through ajax. Is it possible that might be affecting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your elements are pulled in via ajax, that means it is possible that your on'click' event is being assigned before the actual element exists on the document.  You have to wait until after the ajax is done OR do something like

```
$('body').on('click', '#removeproducer', removeProducer);
```

instead.

Doing it the latter way binds the click event to the body, but reacts only when the #removeproducer element is clicked, it will trigger for all #removeproducer elements found in the document at any time.

Comment: I got your reasoning and the point about 'waiting until after the ajax is done', but is there a way to do that?

Comment: It depends on how you are doing your ajax call, but there should be a function where you received the ajax response data, you would do it there (for example, in your $.ajax().done() function call).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are declaring your function as a variable *after* your event handler declaration, and in that instance, the variable hasn't been declared yet and is therefore not available to the event handler. To fix this simply switch `var removeProducer = function () {` to `function removeProducer() {`

Here's a little more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) on why this is happening

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but in my actual code, the function declaration is before the call only just like you mentioned. I have lots of other jquery functions too but only this one seems to be broken. I have edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You should put following line after the function since `removeProducer` is not defined at the time you call it.

```
$("#removeproducer").on("click", removeProducer);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBYY6/)

Comment: Please see my edit above and other comments. It is still not working for me.

Comment: Where exactly can I check that? (as it so happens I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and JQuery). Also want to add that this html is generated from a partial view through ajax. Is it possible that might be affecting this?

Comment: Press F12 and you will be able to find console tab in your browser. Check it after clicking remove button and let me know. Are you loading _ProducerIndex.cshtml via AJAX ?

Comment: Yes, I am loading it via ajax.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks guys. I didn't know that Ajax could mess up with element binding else I would have informed in the question itself.